# On Extending the web application of SharePoint 2013, the sharepoint site gives "HTTP 403 Forbidden" error?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, administration, web-application

I extended one of the web applications of sharepoint 2013, when I opened the site it is giving me error for the web application from which I extended another one. Means the original web application is not opening along with the extended one Why does that happen. The Sharepoint server consists of two front end servers and one back end server.

Answer (score 0):

This type of error is due to wrong AAM settings or IIS bindings.So make sure

- You Alternate Acess Mapping settings are correct.
- if their is any bindings at IIS level should reflect the correct
- If you are using FQDN with Loadbalancer then make sure DNS point to correct entry.

If still having the issue, Its great if yo share the Screen Shots / Error details from ULS / event log if any.